# Mac: export as CLI vs. export in ~/.zshrc

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, zsh

It came to me when I was trying to set the max memory for Node. I was told to enter `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` in the terminal, and it all worked out. However, when I close the terminal and open it again, the environment options was gone. I had to enter it again to set the env.

Later, I was wondering if I can write that option to ~/.zshrc file, and I found it worked once for all.

So, I was thinking if it is just a coincidence, or is it like export in the ./zshrc file a permanent version of export in command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.zshrc` is just a file that gets sourced by every interactive shell, exactly as if you had entered the commands on the command line.

The `.zprofile` file, however, is a better choice for setting environment variables. It's sourced only by login shells, but any non-login interactive shell is likely to inherit its environment from, ultimately, some login shell.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `.zshrc` is only sourced for **interactive** shells. If you need the setting in non-interactive shells as well, `~/.zshenv` would be a better choice.

In either case, you have to aware of the following consequence:

If you manually set the variable in your current shell, with the purpose to **override** the settings done in your dotfile, creating a subshell will again **restore** the settings from the dotfile, overriding your current settings.

If you do not like this effect, you could set the value inside `~/.zprofile`. This will be executed only in a **login-shell** (and of course inherited to all child processes). Only if you create a new login-zsh as a subshell, this file will be sourced again and destroy possible manual changes which you have done in your calling shell.

Another possibility would be to use, i.e., `~/.zshenv`, but set the value only if it does not already have a value yet:

```
: ${NODE_OPTIONS:=--max_old_space_size=4096}
export NODE_OPTIONS
```

Even though this uses two lines instead of only one, this is the approach I recommend, since it allows you to override the value for all subshells if needed, but still ensures that a suitable default is set, if no overriding took place.